# returned no of rows different on left join

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have two sql query in one of them i perform left outer join, both should return same no of records but returned no of rows are different in both the sql queries

```
select Txn.txnRecNo 
from Txn 
inner join Person on Txn.uwId = Person.personId 
full outer join TxnInsured on Txn.txnRecNo = TxnInsured.txnRecNo 
left join TxnAdditionalInsured on Txn.txnRecNo = TxnAdditionalInsured.txnRecNo 
where Txn.visibleFlag=1 
and Txn.workingCopy=1
```

returned 20 records

```
select  Txn.txnRecNo 
from Txn 
inner join Person on Txn.uwId = Person.personId 
full outer join TxnInsured on Txn.txnRecNo = TxnInsured.txnRecNo 
where Txn.visibleFlag=1 
and Txn.workingCopy=1
```

returned 15 records

Comment: Full join to one table and left join to another from the same "left" source? Are you sure join types chosen make sense since you are selecting values from TXN only? `FULL` gives you additional NULLs. `LEFT` gives you the only possibility to multiply rows - it's not used nether in `where` nor in `select`.

Comment: Hi Lokesh, 
Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the `TxnAdditionalInsured`  table have **duplicate records**. use `distinct`

```
select distinct Txn.txnRecNo 
from Txn 
inner join Person on Txn.uwId = Person.personId 
full outer join TxnInsured on Txn.txnRecNo = TxnInsured.txnRecNo 
left join TxnAdditionalInsured on Txn.txnRecNo = TxnAdditionalInsured.txnRecNo 
where Txn.visibleFlag=1 
and Txn.workingCopy=1
```

Answer (score 1):

A `left` join will produce all rows from the left side of the join *at least* once in the result set.

But if your join conditions are such that there are *multiple* rows from the right side that match a particular row on the left, that left row will appear multiple times in the result (as many times as it is matched with a right row).

So, if the results are unexpected, your join criteria aren't are strict as they need to be or you do not understand your data as well as you thought you did.

Unlike the other answers, I would not suggest just adding `distinct` - I'd suggest you investigate your data and determine whether your `ON` clause needs strengthening or if your data is in fact incorrect. Adding `distinct` to "make the results look right" is usually a poor decision - prefer to investigate and get the *correct* query written.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select distinct Txn.txnRecNo --> added distinct here
from Txn 
inner join Person on Txn.uwId = Person.personId 
full outer join TxnInsured on Txn.txnRecNo = TxnInsured.txnRecNo 
left join TxnAdditionalInsured on Txn.txnRecNo = TxnAdditionalInsured.txnRecNo 
where Txn.visibleFlag=1 
and Txn.workingCopy=1
```