# SQL results get doubled when they shouldn't

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I made a query to get an overview about all 'Tickets' we solved for customers per purchase order. I registered 3 different tickets, with 1h working time, 2h working time and 4h working time out of hours. In my Overview I should get the three tickets nicely under each other with the time worked on it, so 3 lines. For some reason I get 6 lines under each other for the 3 tickets so 2 for each ticket. The first one is the sum of the 1 and the 2 working hours, so 3 hours and the second one is the 4 working hours out of hours. I only registered these times on separate tickets but they get added to all tickets and I have no idea how it's possible. I'm thinking it may have something to do with the purchaseorderID?

[image: Result]

```
    SELECT
    po.PurchaseOrderId, 
    po.Reference AS PO,
    po.CustomerPurchaseOrderId AS CustomerPurchaseOrderId,
    po.BudgetPrice,
    ti.subject,
    ti.ticketid,
    SUM(reg.DurationHours) AS DurationHours,
    reg.IsOutOfHours,
    CASE DATEPART(DW, reg.RegistrationDate) WHEN 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsSunday,

    CASE
        WHEN reg.IsOutOfHours = 1 AND CASE DATEPART(DW, reg.RegistrationDate) WHEN 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 1 THEN po2e.HourlyRate * 2
        WHEN reg.IsOutOfHours = 1 AND CASE DATEPART(DW, reg.RegistrationDate) WHEN 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END = 0 THEN po2e.HourlyRate * 1.5
        ELSE po2e.HourlyRate
    END AS HourlyRate
    FROM Registration reg
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee emp ON reg.EmployeeId = emp.EmployeeId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN PurchaseOrder po ON reg.PurchaseOrderId = po.PurchaseOrderId
        LEFT 

OUTER JOIN Ticket ti on ti.PurchaseOrderId=po.PurchaseOrderId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN PurchaseOrder2Employee po2e ON po2e.EmployeeId = emp.EmployeeId AND po2e.PurchaseOrderId = po.PurchaseOrderId
    WHERE po.PurchaseOrderId=1042
    GROUP BY ti.subject, ti.ticketid, po2e.HourlyRate, po.PurchaseOrderId, po.Reference, po.BudgetPrice ,po.CustomerPurchaseOrderId,reg.IsOutOfHours, CASE DATEPART(DW, reg.RegistrationDate) WHEN 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        order by po;
```

[image: Keys]

[image: Registrations]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [returned no of rows different on left join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35885169/returned-no-of-rows-different-on-left-join)

Comment: If this happened to me. I remove table by table to see which is what brings me back duplicates, once found i put another value to compare with this table.

Comment: The easy way to write group by statements: Do as much case/datepart/etc stuff as possible in a derived table. At top level, list all columns in the select list (that are not arguments to a set function) in the group by clause - in the same order!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the reg.isOutOfHours that is causing the problem, try taking that out of the select and GroupBy to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: It indeed gives me only 3 rows but it still ads the hours from the separate tickets together. So now it gives me 3 times 7 hours instead of 1,2 and 4 hours?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the SUM is happening for the PurchaseOrderID and not the TicketID, I'll have a try here but try taking out the PurchaseOrderID from the Select too, I'll get back to you in a bit.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't help :/ It just deletes the column.

Comment: I'm thinking the Registration table where you store the Duration Hours should have a foreign key of TicketID as well as you need to store the Duration of the ticket you're working on.

Comment: I edited the question with a image of the keys on the table

Comment: change the LEFT OUTER JOIN for Ticket to be 

LEFT OUTER JOIN Ticket ti on ti.PurchaseOrderId=po.PurchaseOrderId and reg.TicketId = ti.TicketId

Comment: Ok, so now I only have two columns left. The one with the 4 hours ot of hours and the correct ticketid but the other one is still a sum of the 1 and 2 hours.

Comment: Does the SUM of the 1 and 2 hours happen because the foreign TicketId key in Registration is the same though?

Comment: What do you mean with the same?

Comment: Can you send me a snapshot of the data in the Registration Table, that LEFT OUTER JOIN change should have fixed it for you.

Comment: How can I send you a picture?